# Setting title on a styled control

Tags: .net, wpf, popup, styles

I have created a WPF popup style and using it in many places in the application.
The popup title is defined in the style and I'm not sure how to change it to different values throuhout the application, this is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="PopupContentStyle1" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Grid Height="90" Width="392" Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.092*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.007*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.054*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.115*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.732*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush
                            EndPoint="0.5,1"
                            StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF333C3C"
                                Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF464646"
                                Offset="0.25" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF504E50"
                                Offset="0.75" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF595D59"
                                Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>

                            <Border Background="{DynamicResource TemplateBackgroundColour}" Margin="5,15,5,5" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <Label Name="popupTitle" Content="Sample title" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Foreground="{DynamicResource DefaultFontColour}" Padding="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" />

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

this is how i call and want to change the title to reflect popup content:

```
<Popup x:Name="p1" AllowsTransparency="True">
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle1}" >
            <ContentControl.Content>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox>Popup user control goes here</TextBox>

                </Grid>
            </ContentControl.Content>

        </ContentControl>
    </Popup>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this is making a custom contentcontrol and adding a "popupHeader" dependencyproperty to that class. That way, you can bind your header to that property straight away and you can still use your tag for other purposes.

Make a class like PopUpHeader that inherits from contentcontrol and add a dependencyproperty to it.

Create a class like this:

```
public class PopUpHelper : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PopUpHeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PopUpHeader", typeof(String), typeof(PopUpHelper), null);
    public string PopUpHeader
    {
        get { return Convert.ToString(GetValue(PopUpHeaderProperty)); }
        set { SetValue(PopUpHeaderProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

To be able to reference this in your XAML, input this namespace:

xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"

where "YourNamespace" is the namespace you have put the above class in.

Then change some targettype attributes in your style:

```
<Style x:Key="PopupContentStyle1" TargetType="local:PopUpHelper">
```

and also this line

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:PopUpHelper">
```

change the binding of the content of your label to:

```
Content="{TemplateBinding PopUpHeader}"
```

You can use your new contentcontrol in your xaml like this:

```
<local:PopUpHelper PopUpHeader="This is the header" Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle1}">
    <local:PopUpHelper.Content>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="Here goes content"/>
        </Grid>
    </local:PopUpHelper.Content>
</local:PopUpHelper>
```

If this would fail, check out the sample app I made for this: [download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yecfvm595ghy95l/CSharpSilverlightSandbox.zip?m)

Comment: I have struggled with this for a while ie:to get the title, If you can give me a sample that'll be greatly appreciated

Comment: Updated answer, this should do the trick, and you could further modify the contentcontrol to your needs with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the sample , having some vpn connection issues will let you know soon.

Comment: thanks for that, it worked fine i had to wrap popuphelper with popup to get the placement working `<Popup x:Name="p1" AllowsTransparency="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnPopup}" Placement="Bottom" >
            <local:PopUpHelper PopUpTitle="This is the header" Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle1}">`

Answer (score 2):

You can (mis?)use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) property to store the title on the `ContentControl`

```
<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle1}" Tag="Sample Title" >
 ...
</ContentControl>
```

And in your style set it with `TemplateBinding` to your label content

```
<Label Name="popupTitle" Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}" ... />
```

Or as an alternative solution you can use the [HeaderedContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.aspx) which have a built in `Header` property what you can use as the popup title.

So if you don't need any additional functionality there is no need to create your own "PoupContentControl" because the built in `HeaderedContentControl` gives you the ability to use a `Header` in your Style:

A sample with using

```
<Popup x:Name="p1" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="True" >
    <HeaderedContentControl Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle1}" 
                            Header="Sample title"> 
         <HeaderedContentControl.Content>
             <Grid>
                 <TextBox>Popup user control goes here</TextBox>
             </Grid>
         </HeaderedContentControl.Content>
     </HeaderedContentControl>
</Popup>
```

And in your stlye change the `TargetType` to `HeaderedContentControl` and modify your `Label` to:

```
<Label Name="popupTitle" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ... />
```

Comment: I tried the first suggestion didn't work, since your second suggestion is the proper way can you please explain how to create a PopupTitle which inherits from Popup?

Comment: @melspring I haven't realized how your xaml is built up... I've updated my answer.

Comment: @melspring I've added a sample how to use `HeaderedContentControl` instead of `ContentControl`

Comment: +1 Thanks for your help, I accepted the other answer because it allows me to customise the header with different styling and placement since it is a label.